# In linux, kokila font not working in Google Chrome

Tags: css, linux, google-chrome, fonts

I am using linux, the kokila fonts are not loading in the google chrome but are working fine in firefox, but working fine in windows. I am using the follwing syntax

```
    @font-face {
     font-family:'kokila';
       src:url('../fonts/kokila.ttf') format('truetype');
       src:url('../fonts/kokila.woff') format('woff');
       src:url('../fonts/kokila.eot');
 }
```

any help thanks

Comment: [Check this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)

Comment: @anpsmn, I have tried but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kokila font is a licenced version, that is why it wont work for linux chrome, So I have changed the font to opensans now it is working fine.